# What is the best wat to check if an authenticated user is also an instance of another model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I am authenticating users with the normal auth eloquent driver.
I want to also check if the User (after logged in) is also an instance of another model.
I found out that he has an array with all of model_2's data but checking if that is empty 
sounds like a workaround.
How should I tackle this?

Model 1: Auth::user 
Model 2: Teacher

```
if(Auth::check) {// check for logged in
    if(Auth::user()->is_teacher() ? // -- how can I do this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can work for you:

```
$email = Auth::user()->email;
$match = false;

if (Teacher::where('email','=',$email)->first() != NULL) {
    $match = true;
}

return $match;
```

Comment: Is it good to check like this? !is_object(Auth::user()->teacher) ?

Comment: No, that would check for a property called 'teacher' on your user object. There's a variety of solutions to this. You could use a one-to-one relationship between user accounts and teacher objects. I suggest you come by #laravel on IRC and get some suggestions for the best way to design whatever it is that you're making.

Comment: I've made them with a one-to-one relationship, why does that object conflict with it?